# Unlimited access to posts through API for Facebook/Google+/Instagram

Tags: facebook, google-api, google-plus, instagram-api, facebook-ads-api

For Facebook, Instagram, or GOogle+, is there a program we can participate in that lets us access all public posts through an API on these social media platforms? The public search puts a limit on how many posts we can retrieve so is there one that does not have a limit?

Comment: Contact one of the media partners that have access to Public Feed API at Facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/public_feed/

Answer (score 0):

Facebook and Instagram do not have any program which allows you to access unlimited earned (public) data. Both platforms have very tight (and monitored) rate limits.
Google+ - unsure.